# Regular expression to find the last hyphen, then move two spaces to the right and delete everything from there rightward

Tags: r, regex

I have a series of strings that I would like to use regular expressions to compress.

```
1  617912568590104527563-Congress-Dem-Packages_Nomination-DC2019-08-08.xlsx
2            517912568590504527553-Dem-Plans-Packages_Debate2019-08-08.xlsx
3       47912568590104527523-Congress-Dem-Packages_House2019-08-08 (1).xlsx
```

I would like the result of the regular expression to be the following compressed strings:

```
1  Nomination-DC2019-08-08
2  Debate2019-08-08
3  House2019-08-08
```

Basically, the logic I'm looking for is to find the last hyphen, then move two spaces to the right and delete everything from there rightward. I'm undertaking this in R.

**Update**: I tried the following workflow, which addressed my issue. h/t to @brittenb for identifying the very useful `tools::file_path_sans_ext()`

```
x<-tools::file_path_sans_ext(x)
x<-str_replace(x, " .*", "") 
x<-str_replace(x,".*\\_", "")
```

However, if anyone has a one line regex solution to this that would be great.

**Update 2:** h/t @WiktorStribiżew  for identifying two one-liner solutions:

```
stringr::str_replace(x, ".*_([^.\\s]+).*", "\\1")
sub(".*_([^.[:space:]]+).*", "\\1", x)
```

Comment: Here you go `(?<=_)[^_.]*`

Comment: You can do this without regular expressions. Split the string on the underscore(`strsplit(s, "_")[[1]][1]`), then get the file name without the file extension (`tools::file_path_sans_ext(s)`) and then replace any "(1)" that might exist with `gsub(" (1)", "", s)`. Regex is overkill and should be used as a last resort in most cases.

Comment: @sln thank you so much, unfortunately that removes everything after the first underscore, i need everything removed 2 spaces after the last hyphen...

Comment: @brittenb thank you for this. Im going use your suggested approach.

Comment: `gsub(" (1)", "", s)` is wrong, you probably meant `gsub(" (1)", "", s, fixed=TRUE)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - yes, that's correct. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: `Here you go (?<=_)[^_.]*` do you need usage help ? A symptom might be that you don't know what you're looking at.

Comment: @sln thats virtually the same as above. and in the question i mentioned Im working with hyphens and not underscores...

Comment: @sln answer is working as you request. Look at this demo: https://regex101.com/r/Spuj3J/1

Comment: Oh, you want this `(?<=_)(?<=_)[^-\s.]*(?:-[^-\s.]+)*`  https://regex101.com/r/hVVKFk/1

Comment: @JorgeWanderSantanaUreña its not...

Comment: @sln thank you, im in the R environment and it looks like  '\s' is an unrecognized escape

Comment: Oh, you want this then `(?<=_)[^- \t.]*(?:-[^- \t.]+)*` https://regex101.com/r/bYQazU/1

Comment: @sln, thanks again, but that removes everything after the first underscore. I dont care about the underscores. im looking to remove everything two spaces after the last hyphen (dash).

Comment: Oh, you want this then Find `.*(?<=_)([^- \t.]*(?:-[^- \t.]+)*).*` replace `$1` https://regex101.com/r/QDdUnL/1

Comment: If the engine doesn't like assertions, use this `.*_([^- \t.]*(?:-[^- \t.]+)*).*` There really is 40 ways to skin a cat, we just covered 3

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian If you need real help without guessing games please do what I asked for in the top comment. Update the question and let me know. As you already understand *not that it should make a difference* - it makes a huge difference, escpecially in R where 4 different regex engines are used in different libraries.

Comment: @sln unfortunately that deleted everything. I ran the following in R and it supplied my needed output
`files.df<-mutate(files.df, col1 = tools::file_path_sans_ext(col1))
files.df$col1<-str_replace(files.df$col1, " .*", "")`

Comment: h/t to @brittenb  for providing me with the necessary approach/logic.

Comment: One line solution: no extra libraries - `sub(".*_([^.[:space:]]+).*", "\\1", x)`. [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Spuj3J/5) and the [R demo](https://rextester.com/EAZM58155). With `stringr`: `str_replace(x, ".*_([^.\\s]+).*", "\\1")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, that does it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simplify the task if you use `tools::file_path_sans_ext()` to extract the file name without extensions first and then grab all non-whitespace chars from the last `_`:

```
x <- c("617912568590104527563-Congress-Dem-Packages_Nomination-DC2019-08-08.xlsx", "517912568590504527553-Dem-Plans-Packages_Debate2019-08-08.xlsx", "47912568590104527523-Congress-Dem-Packages_House2019-08-08 (1).xlsx")
library(stringr)
str_extract(tools::file_path_sans_ext(x), "(?<=_)[^_\\s]+(?=[^_]*$)")
```

See the [R demo](https://rextester.com/DALIVD14328). The `(?<=_)[^_\\s]+(?=[^_]*$)` regex matches a location after `_`, then matches 1+ chars other than `_` and whitespaces and then asserts there are 0+ chars other than `_` up to the end of string.

You may achieve what you need without extra libraries:

```
sub(".*_([^.[:space:]]+).*", "\\1", x)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Spuj3J/5) and the [R demo](https://rextester.com/GECRB23268).

With *stringr*:

```
str_replace(x, ".*_([^.\\s]+).*", "\\1")
```

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=.*_(%5B%5E.%5Cs%5D%2B).*):

[image]
**Details**

- `.*_` - any 0+ chars as many as possible to the last occurrence of the subsequent patterns starting with `_`
- `([^.[:space:]]+)` - [Capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) 1 (its value is referenced to with `\1` placeholder, or [replacement backrefence](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html), from the replacement pattern): 1+ chars other than a dot and whitespace (note `\s` does not denote whitespace inside `[...]` in a TRE regex, it does in an ICU regex in *stringr* regex functions)
- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible.

Full code snippet:

```
x <- c("617912568590104527563-Congress-Dem-Packages_Nomination-DC2019-08-08.xlsx", "517912568590504527553-Dem-Plans-Packages_Debate2019-08-08.xlsx", "47912568590104527523-Congress-Dem-Packages_House2019-08-08 (1).xlsx")
sub(".*_([^.[:space:]]+).*", "\\1", x)

library(stringr)
stringr::str_replace(x, ".*_([^.\\s]+).*", "\\1")
```

Both yield

```
[1] "Nomination-DC2019-08-08" "Debate2019-08-08"
[3] "House2019-08-08"
```

Comment: Why the downvote? OP confirmed that it works and the answer contains a detailed explanation. +1